# Rent cloud to build Firefox

Tags: firefox

I am going to customise Firefox for personal use on Mac , Window, and Linux.

But my PC is not power enough to build Firefox quickly. It always take 2 hours, and some time get strange errors.

Is there any service such as rent cloud OS, or likes, that help me config with source ready for build, then I apply some modifications to source, and run build.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rent a VPS server for this. There are a lot of provides who currently only charge you for the time you use the VPS service. So you could rent a faster VPS and use it build firefox. When you would turn the VPS off, you wouldn't be charged for that time.

You can use Amazon AWS, Linode, Digital Ocean, Google Cloud and similar services.

Comment: It is a specific job. I want they help me config build ready, because Firefox require many steps. I don't want to waste time of sticking with problems in middle, would they accept a specific requirement like that.

Comment: You are free to use VPS as you want, I doubt anyone will provide custom services configuring such things for you. You will have to do it yourself or hire someone who can do it.